# Blade - Tailwind Accordion

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, tailwind-ui

I have a small problem. I have a Tailwind Accordion component from Flowbite. Now I have the problem that when I press a x-primary-button within an accordion body, the whole accordion element closes, which is not what I want. Does anyone know a solution? I would be grateful for any help

Here is my code
Blade:

```
<div>
<h1 class="pb-4">Umzugsgut</h1>
@php
    $vorherigerRaum = null;
    $counter = 0;
@endphp
<div id="accordion-flush" data-accordion="open"
     data-active-classes="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
     data-inactive-classes="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
     data-accordion-disable-propagation="true">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        @if($item->raum !== $vorherigerRaum)
            @php
                $counter++
            @endphp
            <h2 id="accordion-flush-heading-{{$counter}}">
                <a href="#"
                        class="flex items-center justify-between w-full py-5 font-medium rtl:text-right text-gray-500 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 gap-3"
                        data-accordion-target="#accordion-flush-body-{{$counter}}" aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="accordion-flush-body-{{$counter}}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation()">
                    <span>{{$item->raum}}</span>
                    <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-3 h-3 rotate-180 shrink-0" aria-hidden="true"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M9 5 5 1 1 5"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </h2>
        @endif
        @php
            $vorherigerRaum = $item->raum;
        @endphp
        <div id="accordion-flush-body-{{$counter}}" class="hidden" aria-labelledby="accordion-flush-heading-{{$counter}}">
            <div class="py-5 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
                <table class="w-full">
                    <thead class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"
                            class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 sm:pl-3">
                            Element
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col"
                            class="px-3 py-3.5 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                            Anzahl
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col"
                            class="px-3 py-3.5 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                            Demontage
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col"
                            class="px-3 py-3.5 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                            Montage
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <tr class="border-t border-gray-300">
                        <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 sm:pl-3">
                            {{$item->name}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="whitespace-nowrap  py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 flex place-content-center">
                                <x-primary-button wire:click="decrement({{ $item->id }})" type="button">-
                                </x-primary-button>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                name="element[{{ $item->raum }}:{{$item->name}}]"
                                id="element[{{ $item->id }}]"
                                class="
                                    block
                                    rounded-md
                                    border-0
                                    bg-gray-200
                                    text-gray-900
                                    dark:bg-gray-700
                                    py-1.5
                                    dark:text-gray-300
                                    sm:text-sm
                                    sm:leading-6
                                    text-center
                                    mx-4"
                                readonly
                                value="{{ $elements[$item->id] }}"
                                autocomplete="off">
                                <x-primary-button wire:click="increment('{{ $item->id }}')" type="button">+
                                </x-primary-button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
                            @if($item->montage == 'on')
                                <input id="checkboxelement[{{ $item->raum }}:{{$item->name}}]"
                                       aria-describedby="demontage-description"
                                       name="demontage[{{ $item->raum }}:{{$item->name}}]" type="checkbox" checked
                                       class="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600">
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
                            @if($item->montage == 'on')
                                <input id="checkboxelement[{{ $item->raum }}:{{$item->name}}]"
                                       aria-describedby="montage-description"
                                       name="montage[{{ $item->raum }}:{{$item->name}}]" type="checkbox" checked
                                       class="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600">
                            @endif
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Livewire component:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\ClientMovingGoods;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $items;
    public $elements = [];
    public $summe;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->items = DB::table('moving_goods_list')->orderBy('raum')->get();
        foreach ($this->items as $item) {
            $this->elements[$item->id] = 0;
        }
    }

    public function decrement($id)
    {
        if ($this->elements[$id] <= 0) {
        } else {
            $item = DB::table('moving_goods_list')->where('id', $id)->first();
            $this->elements[$id]--;
            $this->summe -= ($item->re / 10);
        }
    }

    public function increment($id)
    {
        $item = DB::table('moving_goods_list')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $this->elements[$id]++;
        $this->summe += ($item->re / 10);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter', ['elements' => $this->elements]);
    }
}
```